# webpack4 how to config postcss.config.js file in production mode

Tags: javascript, webpack-4, postcss

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server  --mode development --open --progress --config webpack.dev.config.js",
    "build": "webpack --progress --mode production --config webpack.prod.config.js"
  },



  module.exports = ({env}) => ({
  plugins: {
    'cssnano': env === 'production' ? {} : false
  }
});
```

when I run "npm run build", the env is always "development",so the "cssnano" doesn't run.
How to let the postcss knows that I'm in the "production"?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
module.exports = (env, argv) => ({
…
plugins: {
    'cssnano': argv.mode === 'production' ? {} : false
}
…
```

Comment: I tried this, too. I solved this problem by using "set NODE_ENV=production", because I'm using windows, so I need to add set in the front.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
"build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --mode production --config webpack.prod.config.js"
```

Comment: I tried this, but it turns out it doesn't work on windows, NODE_ENV=productin works on mac, I solved this problem by using "set NODE_ENV=production".